# OverGrive not launching after install

Tags: google-drive

I downloaded the .deb from: https://www.thefanclub.co.za/overgrive (version 3.1.3 beta). However, when I try to launch overGrive from the dash, the window never pops up. I just get the spinning wheel for ~15sec and then nothing. I have tried to remove (apt-get remove --purge overgrive) and reinstall by double clicking the deb package and running dpkg from the command line. It seems to install fine both ways, but I can never get the window to launch. I am on a laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. It installed fine on my desktop with 15.04 and actually has been working great so far. Anyone have any idea how I can try to troubleshoot this more? Thanks!

Comment: Run `python /opt/thefanclub/overgrive/overgrive` in your terminal and add the output to your question.

Comment: Do you have this problem if you are not using the beta version of overgrive?

Comment: @A.B. I got:
"ImportError: No module names oauth2client.client"

For some reason I needed to install google api-python-client. I ran 
"sudo pip2 install --upgrade google-api-python-client" (pip2 because I have python v3 also installed - I wonder if that had something to do with it). After that installed, I was able to run overgrive! 

THanks for your help!!

Also, CharlesGreen, I don't know where I can get any other version. I only see v 3.1.3 beta listed on the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed google's api-python client installed. I don't know why I needed to install it on my laptop and not my desktop, but I ran

```
sudo pip2 install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

Then I was able to run overGrive from the terminal and from the dash.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the bar at the bottom of your desktop and select "+ add applets to the panel".

From the list of applets highlight "System Tray" and click "+ add to panel".

You should now see the OverGrive icon on the panel. Which when you click on it will display the settings menu.

I hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had to execute the following commands:

```
sudo -H pip install --upgrade pip

sudo -H pip2 install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

Several times, and then it worked......